# Set the vim path in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to do the following in bash to modify my `.vimrc`:

```
# *VIM,TMUX-related*
if [(which vim) = '/usr/local/bin/vim'] then
    VIM="/usr/local/bin/vim"
else
    VIM="/usr/bin/vim"
fi
export EDITOR="$VIM"
```

What would be the proper syntax to do this conditional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line should be:

```
if [ "$(which vim)" = '/usr/local/bin/vim' ] then
```

Spaces are needed around `[` and `]`, and you need to use `$(...)` to substitute the output of a command into the command line. You should also put it in quotes in case it returns an empty string or a string containing whitespace.

Comment: ...or use the Bash builtin `[[` / `]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Would it also work for you to directly assign the output of `which vim`? This seems to be the endresult of this snippet:

```sh
export EDITOR="$(which vim)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[["$(which vim)" = "/usr/local/bin/vim"]] && export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/vim"
```

will do the trick if you insist on using conditional statement to make sure that vim path exists.